# How to destroy (or use) large amount of polluted water?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

In my actual Asteroid, I have a huge amount of polluted water.

What is the best way to destroy it (free the space) or use it in large amounts to get the space quickly?

(I don't need to purify it, because I can use several [Steam Geysers](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Steam_Geyser). Do you have any other ideas?)

Answer (score 3):

I would use it in the fertilizer synthesizer.

1) This produces natural gas, which can be used with the natural gas generator to make power.  (The N.G. generator also produces more polluted water, but much less than the fertilizer generators consume).

2) You'll get a lot of fertilizer that you don't need, but storage seems to be unlimited if you just leave solid items on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can boil polluted water to get steam and it will drop polluted dirt. Then you can compost the polluted dirt and do whatever you want with the steam